# Android CameraX video preview is bw and flickering

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I am using CameraX lib in Kotlin environment. My goal is to get a video from a cctv camera connected to an android car navigation tablet. This tablet has a built-in app for this camera and it works fine, the image is clear and colorful.
In my case its bw and its weird
[image: In my case its bw and its weird]

```
private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            // Sel ect back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                .addCameraFilter { it ->
                    it.filter { Camera2CameraInfo.fr om(it).cameraId == "1" }
                }.build()

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview)

            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }
```

What are the solutions for this problem? Any ideas?

I've tried everything
upd. On other devices that have built-in camera (like phones) app performs well and behaves as expected, image is ok